# Assign Global Variable to Function Parameter

Tags: javascript, global-variables

For example:

```
var obj = {};

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    obj = data;
});

console.log(obj)
```

The console then outputs an empty object instead of whatever value `data` was.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    obj = data;
});
```

is an asynchronous function, the code

```
console.log(obj)
```

does not wait for it to stop executing and hence you cannot see anything